# How to Solve Error on this code

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM
(
ITEMCODE CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,
ITEMNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
UNIT_MEASURE VARCHAR(10) CHECK (UNIT_MEASURE IN ('MTR','KG','TONN','LTR','NOS')),
RATE NUMBER(10,2) CHECK (RATE > 0),
STOCK NUMBER(10,2),
MINSTOCK NUMBER(10,2),
MAXSTOCK NUMBER(10,2),
DRAWINGSP VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'DR1000',
CHECK (STORE BETWEEN MINSTOCK AND MAXSTOCK) );
```

Comment: `sql-server` or `mysql`?

Comment: Looks like you have an extra comma between the default and the check for the last field.

Comment: Change `NUMBER` to `NUMERIC`,`STORE` column not exists, change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM
(
   ITEMCODE CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,
   ITEMNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   UNIT_MEASURE VARCHAR(10) CHECK (UNIT_MEASURE IN ('MTR','KG','TONN','LTR','NOS')),
   RATE NUMERIC(10,2) CHECK (RATE > 0),
   STOCK NUMERIC(10,2),
   MINSTOCK NUMERIC(10,2),
   MAXSTOCK NUMERIC(10,2),
   DRAWINGSP VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'DR1000',
   CHECK (STOCK BETWEEN MINSTOCK AND MAXSTOCK) 
);
```

- There is no type `NUMBER` in SQL Server --> Chnage to `numeric`
- There is no column `STORE` --> Change to `STOCK`